# Ubuntu 16.04 driver for Broadcom Limited BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, broadcom

Tried using this: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers), but the [14e4:43a3] (rev 08) isn't listed.

Here's the pertinent output from:  `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       version: 08
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc400000-dc407fff memory:dc000000-dc3fffff
```

I thought it was a kernel issue, but output from: `uname -r`

```
4.4.0-109-generic
```

The wireless was working recently, but between updates I think something happened.

Any thoughts?  I tried running through https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html, but to no avail.  Thanks for any help.

Edit 1:
Per request, the output of: `dmesg | grep brcm`

```
[    9.299788] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    9.299910] brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    9.300085] brcmf_chip_recognition: chip backplane type 15 is not supported
[    9.300087] brcmf_pcie_probe: failed 14e4:43a3
[    9.355666] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd failed with error -2
[    9.355671] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd not found
[ 3906.152283] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd failed with error -2
[ 3906.152285] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd not found
```

Edit 2: 
Result of running:`sudo updatedb && locate brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin`
`/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin`

After running `dmesg | grep brcm` after following the steps:

```
[    9.733367] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    9.733432] brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    9.868201] brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[   10.290149] brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Oct 22 2015 06:16:26 version 7.35.180.119 (r594535) FWID 01-e791c176
[   10.307570] brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
[   10.329437] brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0 wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
[   11.734155] brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlp58s0 already exists
[   11.734155] brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
[   11.905700] brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlp58s0 already exists
[   11.905723] brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
```

Ran `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source` and got:

```
dpkg-query: package 'bcmwl-kernel-source' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

I Ran the purge anyways.

Really not sure what I did, but it's working now.  Maybe I made a change before all of this, and it just needed the reboot?

Anyways, thank you for the help and I hopefully wrote up something in case someone else has the same issue.

Comment: I believe this device uses the driver *brcmfmac*. Please load it: `sudo modprobe brcmfmac` and then check the log for clues: `dmesg | grep brcm` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I tacked it onto the original post.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please check: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source` If it is installed, remove it: `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` Reboot and check again: `dmesg | grep  brcmf` Also show us: `sudo updatedb && locate brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin`

Comment: Solved it.  Thank you for your help.  Don't know how to share my props, but thanks again.

Comment: For the benefit of the searchers, please post the solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what solved the issue, but purging bcwl-kernel-source and rebooting seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Just a tip if you start having problems after resuming from standby/hibernate using Ubuntu 18.04, simply run this command to fix the issue (assuming `dmesg` shows the driver is crashing):
` echo 'SUSPEND_MODULES="brcmfmac"' | sudo tee -a /etc/pm/config.d/config`